# Vue router taking me to parent route mistakenly

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

My Vue router normally works just fine, but when I'm on certain routes and want to navigate to one of the parent routes it instead takes me back to the root redirected route instead of the child route I want it to go to

For example, the route in question is `account-creation`. When I navigate there with `$router.push('/account-creation')` from most routes it works just fine. However, if I navigate there from any of the account details children routes (like `overview`), it instead takes me to /account and not /account-creation!

```
const routes: RouteRecordRaw[] = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: () => import('MainLayout.vue'),
    children: [
      { path: '/', redirect: '/account' },
      { path: 'account', component: () => import('AccountList.vue') },
      { path: 'account-creation', component: () => import('AccountCreation.vue') },
      { 
        path: 'account/:accountId', 
        component: () => import('AccountDetailsLayout.vue'),
        children: [
          { path: 'overview', component: () => import('AccountOverview.vue') },
          { path: 'settings', component: () => import('AccountSettings.vue') },
        ],
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I have tried every manner of solution I could find online, including using fully qualified paths, re-ordering routes, using names routes, all to no avail

I'm pretty sure it's related to the redirect to /account in the root / path, but can't figure out how to maintain that functionality and fix the behavior

How can I ensure navigating to account-creation from account/{id}/overview correctly navigates to account-creation, instead of the redirect route at /account

Things I've tried

- using named paths
- using path: object to route to
- re-ordering routes
- full paths in routes such as /account/:accountId/overview

Comment: Did you try using `$router.push({ path: 'account-creation' });`, My suspect is that it is trying to look for a path at the same level of the 'account' children (overview, settings), but because it is not there, it redirects to the the root route which redirects to the 'account' route. Another approach is to use named routes: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html

Comment: thanks @Diego but that doesn't change the behavior at all :-\ using `$router.push({ path: 'account-creation' });` or `/'account-creation'` doesn't work any differently than my original question

Comment: Your first childpath is very odd, it's now referring to the path `//` instead of `/`; an empty string path should be used instead as 'default child'. I also like putting a catchall route at the end `({path: '*', component: 404.vue})` for routes that can't be matched to avoid weird behavior or crashes. You could check your routing history in vue devtools (or console.log in a beforeEach) to gain better insight as to how your route is interpreted, and share that please, so we're not 'guessing it has to do with X' :)

Comment: Do you really need nested routes? You have set your routes incorrectly as Excalibaard mentioned

Answer (score 2):

It seems there are conflicts on your root routes (every path with "/" in front).
You could check the vue-router documentation for nested routes
[Vue Nested Routes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html)

```js
const routes: RouteRecordRaw[] = [
    {
        path: '/',
        component: () => import('AccountList.vue'),
        alias: '/account'
    },
    {
        path: '/account-creation',
        component: () => import('AccountCreation.vue')
    },
    {
        path: '/account/:accountId',
        component: () => import('AccountDetailsLayout.vue'),
        children: [
            {
                path: 'overview',
                component: () => import('AccountOverview.vue')
            },
            {
                path: 'settings',
                component: () => import('AccountSettings.vue')
            }

    }
]
```

Something like this could work, but as you pointed out the redirect on "/" is a code smell since you load different components.
The MainLayout component will never be mounted with this code, instead you will be redirected to AccountList.

**EDIT**

I edited the original answer based on Excalibaard's comment. You probably should add `<router-view>` in your MainLayout.vue

P.S. `/account` path should be `accounts` as it renders a list

Comment: This could be fixed by putting the mainLayout around the `<router-view>` component, which is probably the reason the accounts were in child routes in the first place. In the old situation, at path `/account`, the first (applevel) `<router-view>` would render MainLayout.vue containing another `<router-view>` which rendered AccountList. Your solution doesn't support this yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing id to the route correctly, then the issue would be that You have to have a child router-view tag in your AccountDetailsLayout.vue in order to display this route with url account/{id}/overview . Since this is the grandchild of the main layout.Just put the router-view tag in your file like this.

```html
AccountDetailsLayout.vue
-----------------------

<template>
------
 <router-view></router-view>
 -----
</template>

<script>

export default {
    name: "AccountDetailsLayout",
    components: {},
    store,
    data() {
        return {};
    },
    computed: {},
    mounted() {},
    methods: {}
};
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

Comment: The OP states "if I navigate there from any of the account details children routes (like `overview`)", so it's implied that the `overview` route is visible, which means `AccountDetailsLayout` already contains `<router-view>`.